# How to stream WEBM Video by Media Source Extensions API

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, media-source

I'm developing video streaming website using **MSE**.

Each video converted to FragmentedMP4 (h264,aac => `avc1,mp4a`)

It is working very fine but what if I wanted to use `webm` format? like YouTube or Facebook they sometimes use it.

I want to know how to get index (like sidx atom in fmp4) from `VP8`, `VP9` or `vorbis` codec
I use **bento4** and **ffmpeg** to get metadata from video and audio
but bento4 is for MP4 Just, and use MP4BoxJS to parse index in browser by JavaScript.

What should I use? `ffmpeg` or what to create fragmented `webm` or something like that and get index stream info to append segments to MSE `SourceBuffer` and sure it should be seekable stream..

Comment: I haven't tested this recently, but you should be able to take the WebM data up to the first `Cluster` element and treat that as your initialization data.  And then, you can split on Clusters from there and arbitrarily seek to them... as long as the Cluster begins with an i-frame.  (If you set your encoder's cluster size to some very high value, this will happen automatically every cluster, since the i-frame requires being at the beginning of the Cluster I think.)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no answers, but if someday someone needs a WEBM parser in JavaScript (Browser or NodeJS),

NOTE1: It's recommended to pass the init+index (not from index.start to index.end) to the function (ArrayBuffer) (In YouTube `Range: bytes=${initRange.start}-${indexRange.end}` (Head ~ Cues).

NOTE2: There is also `parseMP4Segments` for MP4/Sidx.

These functions tested on YouTube (WEBM and MP4) videos and works fine.

Docs (Matroska/WEBM): https://www.matroska.org/technical/elements.html

Docs (MP4): https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/126200_126299/126244/10.02.00_60/ts_126244v100200p.pdf

```
const EBML = {
  HEAD: 0x1a45dfa3,
  Segment: 0x18538067,
  SeekHead: 0x114D9B74,
  SegmentInformation: 0x1549A966,
  Tracks: 0x1654AE6B,
  Cues: 0x1C53BB6B,
  CuePoint: 0xBB,
  CueTime: 0xB3,
  CueTrackPositions: 0xB7,
  CueTrack: 0xF7,
  CueClusterPosition: 0xF1,
  CueRelativePosition: 0xF0,
  CueDuration: 0xB2
};

/**
 * @param {ArrayBuffer} buffer
*/
export function parseWEBMSegments(buffer) {

  const view = new DataView(buffer);

  let SeekHeadPosition = 0, CuesPosition = 0;

  let offset = 0;

  if (view.getUint32() === EBML.HEAD) {

    offset += 4;

    offset = readSize(true);

    if (view.getUint32(offset) === EBML.Segment) {

      offset += 4;

      const end = readSize(true);

      for (; offset < end;) {

        if (view.getUint32(offset) === EBML.SeekHead) {

          SeekHeadPosition = offset;

          offset += 4;

          readValue(readSize(true));

        } else if (view.getUint32(offset) === EBML.SegmentInformation || view.getUint32(offset) === EBML.Tracks) {

          offset += 4;

          readValue(readSize(true));

        } else if (view.getUint32(offset) === EBML.Cues) {

          CuesPosition = offset;

          offset += 4;

          offset = readSize(true);

        }

      }

    }

  }

  offset = CuesPosition;

  function readSize(returnEndOffset = false) {

    const bytes = [view.getUint8(offset)];

    let checker = 0b1000_0000;
    let shifter = 0b0111_1111;

    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

      if (bytes[0] & checker) {

        bytes[0] &= shifter;

        break;

      }

      checker >>= 1;
      shifter >>= 1;

      bytes.push(null);

    }

    offset++;

    for (let i = 1; i < bytes.length; i++) {

      bytes[i] = view.getUint8(offset);

      offset++;

    }

    let size = 0;

    for (const byte of bytes) size = size << 8 | byte;

    return returnEndOffset ? Math.min(offset + size, buffer.byteLength) : size;

  }

  function readValue(end) {

    let value = 0;

    for (; offset < end;) {

      value = value << 8 | view.getUint8(offset);

      offset++;

    }

    return value;

  }

  function safeSkip() {

    offset++;

    const size = readSize();

    offset += size;

  }

  if (view.getUint32(offset) !== EBML.Cues) {

    throw new TypeError("This is not 'Cues' Element");

  }

  offset += 4;

  const end = readSize(true);

  const cues = [];

  for (; offset < end;) {

    if (view.getUint8(offset) === EBML.CuePoint) {

      offset++;
      const end = readSize(true);

      const cue = {};

      for (; offset < end;) {

        if (view.getUint8(offset) === EBML.CueTime) {

          if ("time" in cue) {

            throw new TypeError("Invalid layout, 'CueTime' found multiple times in a single 'CuePoint'");

          }

          offset++;

          cue.time = readValue(readSize(true)) / 1000;

        } else if (view.getUint8(offset) === EBML.CueTrackPositions) {

          offset++;
          const end = readSize(true);

          if (!("positions" in cue)) cue.positions = [];

          const position = {};

          for (; offset < end;) {

            if (view.getUint8(offset) === EBML.CueTrack) {

              offset++;

              position.track = readValue(readSize(true));

            } else if (view.getUint8(offset) === EBML.CueClusterPosition) {

              offset++;

              position.clusterPosition = SeekHeadPosition + readValue(readSize(true));

            } else safeSkip();

          }

          cue.positions.push(position);

        } else safeSkip();

      }

      if (!("time" in cue)) {

        throw new TypeError("Invalid layout, cannot find mandatory 'CueTime' Element inside 'CuePoint'");

      } else if (!("positions" in cue)) {

        throw new TypeError("Invalid layout, cannot find at least one mandatory 'CueTrackPositions' Element inside 'CuePoint'");

      }

      cues.push(cue);

    } else safeSkip();

  }

  return cues;

}

/**
 * @param {ArrayBuffer} buffer
*/
export function parseMP4Segments(buffer) {

  const view = new DataView(buffer);

  let offset = 0;

  let sidxEndPosition = 0;

  for (; offset < buffer.byteLength;) {

    const size = view.getUint32(offset);
    offset += 4;
    const type = view.getUint32(offset);
    offset += 4;

    if (type === 0x73696478) {

      sidxEndPosition = offset + size - 8;

      break;

    }

    offset += size - 8;

  }

  const version = view.getUint8(offset);

  offset += 8;

  const timescale = view.getUint32(offset);

  offset += 4;

  let time = 0, position = 0;

  if (version === 0) {

    time = view.getUint32(offset);

    offset += 4;

    position = sidxEndPosition + view.getUint32(offset);

    offset += 4;

  } else {

    time = Number(view.getBigUint64(offset));

    offset += 8;

    position = sidxEndPosition + Number(view.getBigUint64(offset));

    offset += 8;

  }

  offset += 2;

  const count = view.getUint16(offset);

  offset += 2;

  const segments = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    const size = view.getUint32(offset) & 0x7fffffff;
    const duration = view.getUint32(offset + 4) / timescale;

    const segment = {
      position: position,
      time: time
    };

    segments.push(segment);

    position += size;
    time += duration;

    offset += 12;

  }

  return segments;

}
```